# External CSS not being applied to my GitHub Pages 404 page

Tags: html, css, github, github-pages

I have a 404 error page for my Github pages site, which relies on external CSS and images like so:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>404 Error - Page not found</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='./site.css'>
    <link rel="icon" href="./images/icons/icon.ico">
</head>
```

It is working perfectly alright with my GitHub pages site when the URL contains only one path name. For instance:
[image]

However, when the path name exceeds one path name, the CSS is not being applied:
[image]

My directory structure is like so:

```
root.
│   404.html
│   index.html
│   site.css
│
├───images
│   │   file1.png
│   │   file2.png
│   │   file3.jpg
│   │   file4.png
│   │   file5.jpg
│   │
│   └───icons
│           file6.png
│           file7.ico
│           file8.png
│           file9.png
│           file10.png
│
This is all that's important
```

Would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Use an absolute path instead of a relative one.

You're using a relative path ( `./site.css`) instead of a absolute path (`/site.css`).  When you use `./site.css` it says, in this directory, use the site CSS, relative to the URL. When you add a second directory you're asking for `/blah/site.css`. Simply remove the dot (`/site.css`) to always reference the root directory's CSS File.